# Jupyter notebook (Python 3.6): ImportError: cannot import name 'prange'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, numba

I am using numba to speedup my code. It runs fine in the terminal. But when I try to run it inside jupyter notebook, it gives error for import numba prange. I am using Numba 0.38.1. 
When I try import prange from the temrinal of jupyter, the import works fine.

Can someone please guide me what could be the issue. Thanks

[From the terminal created from Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIRiq.png)

[From the notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tAdW.png)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the import and operation in different cells?

It worked for me. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en1Mo.png)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apparently there was something wrong in the notebook. It started to work fine once I restarted it. Thanks